# Redshift LIKE column value with %

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column that is a comma separated string of values. I want to join another table that only has one of the values. On redshift, how can I do a LIKE operator with '%' injected into the comparison?

Ex:

TableA: values_col = 'abc, def'

TableB: value_col = 'def'

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.value_col LIKE '%' || a.values_col || '%'
```

The above concat doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get awful performance.  You should fix your data structure.  But if you have to, then this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a JOIN
     TableB b
     ON ',' || a.values_col || ',' LIKE '%,' || b.value_col || ',%';
```

The commas are important if your values can contain each other.  More importantly, the `like` needs the operands in the right order.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. What do you suggest for the data structure? Should I flatten the list into n-columns then or just have them be different rows? Thanks.

Comment: @cvax . . . You should not store multiple values in a delimited list.  You should have one row per value.