# Redshift LIKE column value with % in WHERE clause

Tags: string, amazon-redshift, sql-like

I'm trying to make this to work:

```
with a as (select '1'::varchar(32) as x), 
     b as (select '10'::varchar(32) as x)
select *
from b 
left join a using(x)
where b.x like '%1%'
;

x    
---- 
10
```

1 record(s) selected [Fetch MetaData: 0ms] [Fetch Data: 0ms]

but what I need to use is:

```
where b.x like '%' || a.x || '%'
;

x    
---- 

0 record(s) selected [Fetch MetaData: 0ms] [Fetch Data: 0ms]
```

Any ideas?

I've put this question even here [Redshift LIKE column value with %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777225/redshift-like-column-value-with)
where the idea comes from.

Thanks

Comment: Please share input data and expected output. Why do you want to use second syntax?

Comment: have a look at strpos function to see whether a is within b

Comment: @Swapnil, the expected output is in the first block, x=10

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566). You can always post an answer if it is different from the current answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strpos function to see whether a is within b

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STRPOS.html

```
where strpos(b,a) > 0
```

Comment: When I us strpos() in this way
    Select strpos('10', '1') >0
then works, in other words, it's 'TRUE' but it doesn't in the code below.
    with a as (select '1'::varchar(32) as x),
            b as (select '10'::varchar(32) as x)
     select *
     from b 
     left join a using(x)
     where strpos(b.x, a.x) > 0
     ;
What I'm missing?

Comment: @gafeta In your example, `a.x = b.x` (due to the `using(x)`), therefore the answer will _always_ be zero. I suggest you edit your question to show a sample input table and then a sample of the output you desire, then we can assist you better.

Comment: @John Rotenstein you are totally right. Thanks for the input, I think I've not one but two solution for this now.